# Library not working on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, xcode8

Hello I'm using a library in my project, and basically it's working on real devices, but not on simulator. 
I would like to know how to add compatibility with simulator also.

I've search around, and I found some answers that should have solved my problem, but they're not doing it. (Maybe I'm doing things wrong, but still not working).

I'm getting this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Library",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in class.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried it on xcode7 and xcode8.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us more detailed error log? Open Xcode Report Navigator window and select your build with an error. Then find that error in the main Xcode window and copy full error log.

Comment: that's all i have :/ 
Showing Recent Issues
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Library", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in class.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you embedded the framework, and made sure the framework search paths are correct?

Comment: I think so, otherwise it won't be working on device either, right?

Comment: What library/framework do you use? Some of them are not intended to be used on simulator

Comment: It is not a public library. A partner of mine created it :/. But it it just encrypt a number

Comment: Write the output of the: "lipo -detailed_info %library_filename%". It will tell which architectures this binary supports

Comment: Where do I write it, on the xcode console? (it is not recognizing lipo command) EDIT: oh okay on the termianl i supose, i'm trying it

Comment: Well i'm not getting any information with that... :\ i'm sure it does not support x86 (Simulator..), so I need to add compatibility, but i do not want to create it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're using a framework or library which was only built for ARM architecture. In that case you'll have to create fat binary which will include code for all platforms (x86 for simulator, ARM and ARM64 for iOS devices).

Comment: Can I just make mine compatible? add compatibility  with a script or whatever?